# Calculate Quantization error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, pcm, quantization

iI was given this solution to a problem in my course material.

**Problem:**

a signal `x(t)` sampled at `10 sample/sec`. consider the first `10 samples` of `x(t)`

```
x(t) = 0.3 cos(2*pi*t);
```

using a 8-bit quantiser find the quantisation error.

**solution:**

```
(256 quantisation levels)
t=1:10;
x=(0.3)*cos(2*pi*(t-1)/10);
mx=max(abs(x));
q256=mx*(1/128)*floor(128*(x/mx));
stem(q256)
e256=(1/10)*sum(abs(x-q256))
Error: e256 = 9.3750e-04
```

There was no explanation on this, can you explain how this was calculated in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first two code lines I prefer,

```
Fs = 10;
L = 10;
t = (0 : L - 1) / Fs;
x = 0.3 * cos(2 * pi * t);
```

where `Fs` is sampling frequency, `L` number of samples and `t` shows the time.

Note that `x` is sinusoidal with frequency of `Fx = 1 Hz` or we can say that it's periodic with `Tx = 1 sec`.

For `8-bit` quantization we have `256` levels. Since `L / Fs = [10 sample] / [10 sample/sec] = 1 sec` is equal to `Tx` (a whole period of `x`) we can work with positive samples.

```
mx = max(abs(x));
```

`mx` is defined because in order to use `floor` we need to scale the `x`.

```
q256 = mx*(1/128)*floor(128*(x/mx));
```

`mx` shows the maximum value for `x` so `x / mx` will take values over `[-1 1]` and `128*x/mx` over `[-128 128]` will cover all `256` levels.

So we will quantize it with `floor` and scale it back (`mx*1/128`).

```
e256 = (1/L)*sum(abs(x-q256))
```

`e256` simply shows the mean error over 10 samples.

Note that if `L / Fs < Tx` then this quantization won't be the optimum one.

**Have in mind**

The answer that you are given has some problems!

suppose `x = [-1 -.2 0 .7 1];` and we want to quantize it with `2` bits.

```
mx = max(abs(x));
q4 = mx * (1/2) * floor(2*(x/mx));
```

Will give `q4 = [-1 -0.5 0 0.5 1]` which has `5` levels (instead of `2^2 = 4`).

It might not be a big problem, you can delete the level `x=1` and have `q4 = [-1 -0.5 0 0.5 0.5]`, still the code needs some improvements and of course the *error* will increase.

A simple solution is to add

```
[~,ind] = max(x);
x(ind) = x(ind) - 1e-10;
```

after definition of `mx` so the maximum values of `x` will be quantized in one level lower.

The error will increase to `0.0012`.

Comment: thats true. if i was asked to find the error using a 2-bit quantiser can i simply subtract the original signal from the quantised signal and plot the error(on matlab).

Comment: @connor991, I provided a simple solution with the given code. See if it helps. Good luck.